# Python 3.4.1 how to get 1 out of 01

Tags: python, python-3.x

So for an assignment for class the instructor wants us to create a program that is similar to a time clock. You enter the time that you start and enter the time that you leave and the program figures out how much the person gets paid. However, the program has to be in a 24 hour format so for example, if you want to type in 2 p.m. you need to type in `14:00`. With that logic, what if you were to work until the early hours of the morning such as `01:00`? I have the program prompt the user for the times as follows:

```
start = input("Enter the start time:")
end = input("Enter the end time:)
```

I then use `start.split(":")` and `end.split(":")` to create a list separated by the `":"` and I use `eval()` afterwards to obtain the integer but whenever I try to enter an integer that has a 0 in front of it (such as `01`) the program responds with a syntax error and that it is an invalid token.

Is there any way around this to obtain the number value?

Comment: What about checking if the first character is 0 and removing it if it is 0?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use `eval()`. Use the [`int()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) to parse strings representing integers.

You can safely pass zero-padded numbers into `int()`; `int('01')` returns 1:

```
>>> int('01')
1
>>> int('12')
12
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another way you can strip the values. 
You can user `str.startswith` function

```
start = input("Enter the start time:")
end = input("Enter the end time:")

if (str.startswith(start,"0")):
    print(start[1:])
```

OUTPUT:

```
Enter the start time:01:00
Enter the end time:02:00
1:00
```